# Linq Left Join not working

Tags: linq

I am trying to get this query into Linq

```
SELECT [ID], [Name], LastSync, Phase
FROM [Store] 
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT GLog.[StoreId] AS [StoreId], LastSync, Phase
    FROM [GGCSyncLog] AS GLog 
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT MAX(G1.[DateTime]) AS LastSync, G1.[StoreId]
        FROM [GGCSyncLog] AS G1
        GROUP BY G1.[StoreId]
        ) AS G2 ON (GLog.[StoreId] = G2.[StoreId]) AND (GLog.[DateTime] = G2.[LastSync])
    ) AS MostRecentLog ON Store.[ID] = MostRecentLog.[StoreId]
```

Its results are

```
ID  Name                 LastSync     Phase
1   Sarasota             2010-07-31   5
2   Wellington           2010-07-31   8
3   Tampa International  2013-03-12   8
5   Events               NULL         NULL
6   PO Holding Store     NULL         NULL
```

My Linq returns the correct results except I'm missing the two rows with the null LastSync & Phase. Any idea what's wrong?

```
from s in Stores
join gLog in 
(from g1 in GGCSyncLogs.DefaultIfEmpty()
join g in 
(from g in GGCSyncLogs
group g by g.StoreId into gM
   select new {
   StoreId = gM.Key, LastSync = gM.Max(gg=>gg.DateTime) })
   on new {g1.StoreId, LastSync = g1.DateTime} equals new {g.StoreId,  g.LastSync}
     select new {g1.StoreId, g.LastSync, g1.Phase})
     on s.ID equals gLog.StoreId
        select new {s.ID, s.Name, 
            LastSync = (gLog != null ? (DateTime?)gLog.LastSync : null), 
            Phase = (gLog != null ? (int?)gLog.Phase : null) }
```

Comment: In Linq `join` is same as *inner join*. For *left join* use `join .. into` syntax.

Comment: Got it. That's exactly the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use an "into"

```
from s in Stores
join gRec in
(from g in GGCSyncLogs
join g2 in 
(from g1 in GGCSyncLogs
group g1 by g1.StoreId into gM
  select new {StoreId = gM.Key,LastSync = gM.Max(gg=>gg.DateTime)})
  on new {g.StoreId, LastSync = g.DateTime} equals new {g2.StoreId, g2.LastSync}
    select new {g.StoreId, g2.LastSync, g.Phase})
    on s.ID equals gRec.StoreId into gRec2
    from gRec3 in gRec2.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new {s.ID, s.Name, 
                    LastSync = (gRec3 != null ? (DateTime?)gRec3.LastSync : null),
                    Phase = (gRec3 != null ? (int?)gRec3.Phase : null) }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should read about [`join` clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040.aspx) and [How to: Perform Left Outer Joins](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397895.aspx).

It's hard to get working solution without database here, but hope this will help you get back on track:

```cs
var g2 = from g1 in GGCSyncLogs
         group g1 by g1.StoreId into gM;

var MostRecentLogs = from gLog in GGCSyncLogs
                     join g in g2 on new { gLog.StoreId, LastSync = gLog.DateTime} equals new { g.StoreId, g.LastSync }
                     select new { gLog.StoreId, LastSync = gLog.Date, Phase = gLog.Phase };

var results = from s in Stores
              join gLog in MostRecentLogs on s.Id equals gLog.StoreId into gl
              from l in gl.DefaultIfEmpty(new { LastSync = null, Phase = null })
              select new {
                  s.Id,
                  s.Name,
                  l.LastSync,
                  l.Phase
              };
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but I'd worked this out in the mean time with help from the first comment.